# My ASP.NET Application - Drives me crazy, can't remove it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, page-title

So I edited:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #AboutMeSection {
            border-right: 1px dashed #333;
                min-height:100px;
                height:100px;
        }

    </style>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Adam Kościelniak</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js")
    <script>
    tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
    </script>

</head>
```

of _Layout.cshtml

in the view I simply do:

```
@model KoscielniakInfo.ViewModels.CV
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Virtual CV";
}
```

Even changed the _ViewStart.cshtml so it explicitly changes it:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adam Kościelniak Homepage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

NOTHING still after a 10 deploys I go to my domain: 
adamkoscielniak.pl 
and see this: 
[image: Screenshot]

Where else can I change this? What am I missing?
The full project is on github...
https://github.com/Tackgnol/KoscielniakInfo

Web Deploy Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: That text is not in your codebase, are you sure you are deploying correctly?

Comment: Hi David, this is why it is driving me CRAZY ;)
I have edited my question with a deploy screenshot. 
I think its the way it should be not going to pretend to be a master at it..

Comment: The deploy is probably not including the files or is not overwriting them. Check that is working first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in your layout template. From the top of the solution, look into the folder Views > Shared > _Layout.cshtml

In the header lines

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
```

If you every run into something like this that you cannot find then you can also do ctrl + F to open up the search panel and search for the characters through the entire solution to locate where they are.

Edit: Just read you were modifying the _layout file. Just do the ctrl + f and search for the string solution wide.

Edit: Just downloaded your solution and that line is literally nowhere. Make sure you are deleting all the current files in the directory when you deploy the new code. Just manually delete and redeploy the first time then change your settings to remove all files on deploy after that. Also do a ctrl f5 to make sure your browser isnt caching the header info once you redeploy.

Comment: I'm having a different issue where I see © 2021 - My ASP.NET Application at the bottom of my app locally but it's nowhere in the code base. When deployed it doesn't show in the other environments, seems like IIS express is injecting it somehow

Comment: Couldn’t tell you without seeing, Check your _ViewStart file to see if they layout file is defined as some other location on the server, maybe a generic template the company uses for all. Since chtml extensions don’t need to be compiled in your solution to run, I’ve seen some weird voodoo happening before.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure this is coming from **_Layout.cshtml**

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
```

Make some changes in the file and try publishing again (add some dummy text). Because unchanged file will be skipped when you are deploying.